# Access to preprocess variables in a custom block

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I have created a custom block to display some contact information.

I have a preprocess function that sets a contact variable like so:

```
function atstump_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
    $vars['contact'] = array(
        'name' => 'Doug Gillum',
        'business' => 'Portland Stump Grinding',
        /...
    );
}
```

I enabled the PHP filter, and set this as the text:

```
<ul>
  <li><?php print $contact['name']; ?></li>
  <li><?php print $contact['phone']; ?></li>
  <li><?php print $contact['email']; ?></li>
</ul>
```

However it doesn't recognize $contact as a proper variable and generates the PHP error E_NOTICE:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: contact in eval() (line 2 of C:\xampp\htdocs\stumpgrinding\modules\php\php.module(75) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: contact in eval() (line 3 of C:\xampp\htdocs\stumpgrinding\modules\php\php.module(75) : eval()'d code).
Notice: Undefined variable: contact in eval() (line 4 of C:\xampp\htdocs\stumpgrinding\modules\php\php.module(75) : eval()'d code).
```

Is it even possible to access the preprocess variables in a PHP filter? if not, is there a better way than hard coding them? maybe `variable_set` and `variable_get` and how would I set that up via the theme, I'd rather not make a module for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work.
If you use a preprocess function, the variables will be available in the template of the block.

I think that, in your case, you should edit the settings.php file and add the following line:

```
$GLOBALS['email1'] = 'example@email.com';
```

You'll be able to use the variable `$email1` through the whole site.

Have in mind that it's not a good Drupal practice.

Comment: Just print out some information I don't want to hard code into the template because I am printing the same contact info in more than one place. I'd like a single location for storing the data for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to **add variables** in the **site information** variables table using the hook hook_form_FORM_ID_alter as follows:

```
function mymodule_form_system_site_information_settings_alter ( &$form, &$form_state ) {
    $form['contact'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Contact'),
    );
    $form['contact']['contact_name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Contact name'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('contact_name', ''),
        '#size' => 40,
    );
}
```

Then in the **php filter** input you can get these variables using:

```
<?php echo variable_get('contact_name', '');?>
```